# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"btn btn-special btn-small color-grey"}

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, browser-automation

I try to click automated with python selenium on a button.

I tried to click on this button:

```
<li class="dealers-show-more"><span class="btn btn-special btn-small color-grey">Mehr anzeigen</span></li>
```

using below code:

```
browser.get("https://www....html")
print("Seite geöffnet")
action = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("btn btn-special btn-small color-grey")
for i in range(100):
    action.click()
    print("fertig")
browser.close()
```

Below is the Error that I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\T430\Desktop\Datenerfassung\optiker\eschenbach_links1.py", line 16, in 
>       action = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("btn btn-special btn-small color-grey")
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"btn btn-special btn-small color-grey"}
>     (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the css that you have to use.

```
.btn.btn-special.btn-small.color-grey
```

Always make sure the class will be denoted with `.` and replace the white space with `.`

Comment: I am not sure if you want to click on the button 100 times are you have 100 such buttons to be clicked. In both the cases you need  to get the button in the for loop otherwise you will get StaleElementException as generally selenium will refresh the elements reference when you click on element.